# Search with multiple languages on Azure Search

Tags: azure, search, localization, azure-cognitive-search

I have a database which holds keywords for items, and also their localizations in different languages (supporting around 30 different languages right now), if there are any for that item. I want to be able to search these items using Azure Search. However, I'm not sure about how to set up the index architecture. Two solutions come to my mind in this scenario:

Either I will

1) have a different index for each language, and use that language's analyzer for that index. Later on, when I want to search using this index, I will also need to detect the query language coming from the user, and then search on the index corresponding to that language.

or

2) have a single index with a lot of fields that correspond to the different localizations of the item. Azure Search has support on having language priorities when searching, so knowing the user's language may come in handy, but is not necessarily a must.

I'm kind of new to this stuff, so any pointers, links, ideas etc. will be of tremendous help, even if it doesn't answer the question directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 2 is what we recommend (having a single index with one field per language). You can set some static priorities by assigning field weights using a scoring profile. If you are able to detect the language used in a query, you can scope the search to just that language using the searchFields option.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I will try this approach. I'm not sure if I can detect the language used in the query, but I can try using the location of the user to predict the language.

Comment: What the problem of option 1?

Comment: Two problems with option 1: First, language detection is hard. Second, you may want to allow searches that could be in one of a number of different languages. Having data in different indexes means you'd have to execute multiple queries, and find some way of reconciling multiple results yourself.

Comment: @BruceJohnston if you already knew the user's language then problems 1 & 2 don't really apply. However, I think it would still make sense to go with option 2 because it would be a). Cheaper and b). The query logic is simpler because you are only changing the query string and not the URL. Let me know what you think?

Comment: Cheaper in terms of cost or performance? Also, having to reconcile results from multiple indexes is much harder than any differences in how you would construct the requests.

Comment: Cheaper in terms of cost. I am actually of the same conclusion as you but for different reasons. My point is if you know the user's language, say enGB, then you are only going to hit the enGB index. So there isn't any need to reconcile results from multiple indexes. But creating multiple indexes is costly.

Comment: Azure Search is billed by search unit, not by index. But yes, if the language is known, you only need one index anyway.